# Panel for drag and drop image file, with java swing

Tags: java, image, swing, drag-and-drop

I'm trying to make a java swing panel, where you can drag and drop images. And save the images displayed on the panel.
I found [this](http://www.java2s.com/Code/Java/Swing-Components/GlassPaneDragDrop.htm) which I think would help me a lot.
But on my computer with windows 7 does not work. I can not drag images to the application. I would appreciate any advice. thanks

Answer (score 2):

Rule one, don't mess with things you don't understand ;)

Rule two, fake it till you make it ;)

Replace the `initComponents` method with...

```
private void initComponents() {

    listScroller = new javax.swing.JScrollPane();

    imageList = new JList();
    imageList.setSelectionMode(javax.swing.ListSelectionModel.SINGLE_SELECTION);
    imageList.setLayoutOrientation(javax.swing.JList.HORIZONTAL_WRAP);
    imageList.setVisibleRowCount(-1);
    listScroller.setViewportView(imageList);

    setLayout(new BorderLayout());
    add(listScroller);
}// </editor-fold>//GEN-END:initComponents
```

In the `GlassPaneDragAndDrop` constructor, replace the `paintComponent` method of the "drop pane" with...

```
setContentPane(new JPanel(new BorderLayout()) {
    private BufferedImage image = null;

    @Override
    public boolean isOpaque() {
        return imageList.getModel().getSize() > 0;
    }

    @Override
    protected void paintComponent(Graphics g) {
        Rectangle clip = g.getClipBounds();

        g.setColor(Color.WHITE);
        g.fillRect(clip.x, clip.y, clip.width, clip.height);
    }
});
```

This will allow it to run.  Under Windows 7, you may not like the result though....

Comment: Thanks, and sorry for my stupidity, but I can not do walk with those changes.

Comment: What do you mean you "can't walk with those changes"?

Comment: Works fine for me.  What doesn't work?  Remember, it will only accept files that end with ".png" and ".jpg" (case sensitive)